# how to merge duplicate elements?

Tags: python

I have one list 'l' and their corresponding values 'v':

```
l = ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

v = [3, 2, 3, 5]
```

how to merge duplicate elements?
The expected result is:

```
res_l = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
res_v = [(3, 2), 3, 5]
```

I tried as:

```
L = set(l)
for x in L:
```

...

Comment: Why is `(3, 2)` in its own `tuple`?

Comment: "Yes" is not an answer to "why."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Well, because 3 and 2 are corresponding elements of 'X'.

Comment: Can you show your code attempt for this please?

Comment: @jean does the order matter? or do you just want to merge it? as in would `l = ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']` produce the same output as `l = ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z']`

Comment: @LuisFHernandez order matters.

Comment: @jean so `l = ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z']` and `v = [3, 2, 3, 5]` would output `l_res = ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z']` and `v_res = [3, 2, 3, 5]` ?

Comment: @jean I updated my answer try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `defaultdict` and then just calling `values()`.

Assuming, based on your requirements that the two lists are actually equal length and are with respect to each other, you can iterate over one and reference the other to build your dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

v = [3, 2, 3, 5]

n = defaultdict(list)

for a, b in zip(l, v):
    n[a].append(b)

print(n.values()) # [[3], [3, 2], [5]]
```

If you actually need tuples, I suppose you can do this:

```
print([tuple(d) for d in n.values()]) # [(3,), (3, 2), (5,)]
```

Comment: is it also possible to do with list indexing without importing anything?

Comment: @jean I suppose. But why?

Comment: Why not use `zip()` instead of `enumerate()`? It'd then be `for a,b in zip(l,v): n[a].append(b)`.

Comment: because i am very new of defaultdict

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks. I don't know why it did not occur to me, but much nicer. Cheers.

Comment: @jean Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setdefault`:

```
l = ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
v = [3, 2, 3, 5]

lv = list(zip(l,v))

new_lv = {}
for k,v in lv:
    new_lv.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print (new_lv.items())
```

Output:`[('Y', [3]), ('X', [3, 2]), ('Z', [5])]`

```
print (new_lv.values())
```

Output:`[[3], [3, 2], [5]]`

```
print ([tuple(i) for i in new_lv.values()])
```

Output:`[(3,), (3, 2), (5,)]`

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like:

```
l = ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
v = [3, 2, 3, 5]

l_res = [l[0]]
v_res = [v[0]]
prev = 0
for i in range(1,len(l)):
    if l[prev] == l[i]:
        if type(v_res[-1]) is tuple:
            v_res[-1] = v_res[-1] + (v[i],)
        else:
            v_res[-1] = (v_res[-1],v[i],)
    else:
        l_res.append(l[i])
        v_res.append(v[i])
    prev = i
```

Comment: Read the question again and pay attention to the required output